# send input and it's value using Form Data

Tags: php, node.js, form-data

I have a RefId and I want to send this RefiId through a post request to a url ("https://bpm.shaparak.com"). i have a sample code for do this. but this sample wrote in php and I want do similar in NodeJS but I don't know php very well. sample code for send this post request in php is something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
    function postRefId (refIdValue) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
        form.setAttribute("action", "https://bpm.shaparak.com");         
        form.setAttribute("target", "_self");
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");              
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "RefId");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", refIdValue);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);

        document.body.appendChild(form);         
        form.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(form);
    }
</script>
```

and postRefId call in code :

```
if ($ResCode == "0") {
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>postRefId('" . $res[1] . "');</script>";
}
```

I write above code in NodeJs something like this:

```
postRefId(refIdValue){
  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append('name', 'RefId');
  bodyFormData.append('RefId', refIdValue);

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://bpm.shaparak.com',
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript' }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('postRefId success',response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        console.log('postRefId error',response);
    });
}
```

but when I call this method i get a response from "https://bpm.shaparak.com" that RefId is null. that means could not read RefId from my form. how should i send correct form in nodejs?

Comment: I research in last week. but i don't understand. i create a soap client using soap library in npm. but in this part i just want to send a form to this url. like it implementation in php. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: ok. I am correcting my words. i want to send form request to a specific Url and send RefId as a parameter to this @MagnusEriksson

Comment: sorry, I edited my question title and body @MagnusEriksson

Comment: One hour in and you've completely changed the question. I'm out...

Comment: yes. because i don't understand my problem. thank you and sorry @MagnusEriksson

Comment: So why did you include soap in the question to begin with if the question doesn't have anything to do with it? Please make sure your question is _on point_ with a proper description of the issue (without adding irrelevant fluff) before you post it. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: now i think my question is correct.